# Ensure one thing, and then another one if first is false

Tags: serenity-js

I have an interface with a list of users and a possibility to add a new one. I want to assert that this user is new (i.e. its email is not already used). So I should check that we have no message pop-up.

```
    checkMailIsNotUsed: () =>
        Task.where('#actor checks mail present message is absent',
        Ensure.that(UsersList.messageArea, not(isVisible()))),
```

However this message area could be visible but not with the error messsage I don't expect. So I am looking for, in case above ensure fails, a way to ensure that the text does not include 'already exists'.

```
    Ensure.that(Text.of(UsersList.messageArea), includes('already exists'))),
```

However if the first 'ensure' is false, everything stops. There is no 'or' or equivalent at the Ensure level. I need to do the second Ensure if first one fails.
How could I do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```js
Task.where('#actor checks mail present message is absent',
    Check.whether(UsersList.messageArea, isVisible())
    .andIfSo(
        Ensure.that(Text.of(UsersList.messageArea), includes('already exists')
    )))
    ),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.